# R Data Frame - Convert words in mostly numeric column to zero

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which contains a name column and a value column:

```
a <- c("Bob","Jane","Susan","Greg")
b <- c(10, "Jane", 14, "Greg")
df = data.frame(a,b)
df
      a    b
1   Bob   10
2  Jane Jane
3 Susan   14
4  Greg Greg
```

I'd like to convert the words in column B to zeros like so:

```
    a    b
1   Bob   10
2  Jane    0
3 Susan   14
4  Greg    0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `df$b = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "0", df$b))`

Comment: `ifelse(grepl('\\D', df$b), 0, df$b)`, also works but it only if `df$b` is not stored as a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd coerce `b` to `numeric` and leave it at that. Because `b` is initially a `factor`, I'm first coercing it to `character`.

```
df$b = as.numeric(as.character(df$b))
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion 
df$b
#[1] 10 NA 14 NA
```

In one more step you could replace `NA` with `0` if you want (but I would just keep `NA`)

```
df$b[is.na(df$b)] = 0
df$b
#[1] 10  0 14  0
```

Of course you could use `gsub` to substitute non-digit characters (`\\D+`) with `"0"`. Note that `gsub` automatically coerces to `character`.

```
gsub(pattern = "\\D+", replacement = "0", x = df$b)
#[1] "10" "0"  "14" "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an R expert, but I believe, in accordance with the comment above, `df$b = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "0", df$b))` would work just fine.

More specifically, change your code to:

```
a <- c("Bob","Jane","Susan","Greg")
b <- c(10, "Jane", 14, "Greg")
df = data.frame(a,b)
df$b = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "0", df$b))
df
```

It is the same code you have, but with the new line that manipulates the b vector using [as.numeric](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/numeric) to convert to numbers and gsub, which allows you to iterate over a vector and apply a regular expression to each value ([more information](http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/gsub.php)).

The first argument of gsub is the regular expression - in this case we are using `[^0-9]`, which will match any value that is not numeric (keep in mind this may need to be changed if special characters are possible in your numbers). Regular expressions can easily and conveniently be tested here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

The second argument is what to replace the current value with if the regex does not pass.

The third argument is the vector to iterate across.

The new vector is then passed to the `as.numeric` method.

The code snippet below can be seen on R-Fiddle, [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=7MEflp5p&version=1)

Again, I am not an R programmer, but I think this answers your question.